# Handling native crash on customer android device

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've been reading a lot about handling native crashes in Android. As far as I can tell it all comes down to the `tombstone_**` files, `ndk-stack` and `addr2line`. These tools are very handy with my own device and `adb` ready to fetch the tombstone or logcat, but what do I tell the customer if I can't reproduce his crash? Send me the tombstone?

I know the next question is a stretch because tombstones are generated in a crash scenario (not much the app can do when it's crashing) but are there ways to store the tombstone in logs that the user can send with a press of a button?

P.S. Unfortunately services like `crashlytics` aren't a good solution in the current scenario.

Comment: I know some scenarios for which crashlytics is not a good solution, but in these scenarios the alternative methods are irrelevant, too. But hopefully you *can* make crashlytcis work in your case, this would make your life so much easier.

Comment: It's a client wish for such services not to be used. Anyway, I think we found some kind of workaround. Turns out the customer can activate debug settings and send us the tombstones through "Send Logs" feature. This is a bit complicated for the customer and he may want to turn off the Developer settings afterward but I don't see an alternative. I was happy enough that .o files worked with tombstones from release app built on another computer. Will have to work like this for now.